# filter in angular 2 table app

Tags: angular, typescript

I`ve created a simple table application in angular 2.

And now, my task is create a filter of data in `<input>` tag.

```
<tr>
      <td><input type="" name="" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="" name="" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="" name="" value="" size="7" (keyup)="_service.getServices()"></td>
</tr>
```

i get data with this:

```
private _url = 'http://150.746.21.851/api/v1/';

constructor(private _http: Http) {

}

getServices(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

And this is `_service`

```
constructor(public _service: TableComponentService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getServices()
            .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
    }
```

I dont have any logs of errors. When i input some word in `<input>`, nothing happens. Maybe mistake in syntax?

UPD:

```
@Component({
selector: 'tablecomponent',
templateUrl: 'app/table.template.html',
providers: [TableComponentService]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
lists: any[];

constructor(public _service: TableComponentService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getServices()
            .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
    } 

}
```

and this is part of template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table, table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" align="center">Перечень объектов по теме</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>vol 1</th>
                <th>vol 2</th>
                <th>vol 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background: #F5F5F5">
                <td><input type="" name="" value=""></td>
                <td><input type="" name="" value=""></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="" name="" value="" size="7" (keyup)="_service.getServices()"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor='let list of lists'>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{ list.name }}</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">{{ list.location }}</td>
            </tr>
         <tbody>
```

Comment: what do you want to do? How would you filter data?

Comment: @micronyks  in <input> tag i write some symbol , and then find full word. For example, write A - and then find Alpha

Comment: So does webapi return proper result(json object)?

Comment: @micronyks my webapi return only data json data

Comment: update your code with *ngFor part. or show that code where you used `lists `object

Comment: @micronyks i`ve update my question

Comment: code should work ! strange !

Comment: Can you be sure that on every `keyup event` you get `desire data` in `this.lists` object?

Comment: @micronyks what does it mean, `desire data` in `this.lists`??

Comment: do you get `filtered` data in `this.lists` on keyup event?

Comment: @micronyks i think  no

Comment: Hmmm That's the cause of your problem.

Comment: @micronyks and how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Solution is simple. When you hit API, you need to be sure that you get correct data in json format.

Comment: @micronyks you mean that i used to `*ngFor` derictive?

Comment: Yes.  let's say your current this.lists object contains 100 records. Now when you type in `A` in input, webapi is hit and according to written logic it finds 10 records.Now, webapi returns those 10 records. Now when you subscribe to that result, your `this.lists` should have only 10 records (not 100 records) . If this happens, you will automatically have filter on keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to create a custom pipe to filter your data.**
1. Create a new file for your custom pipe *ex: my-filter.pipe.ts*

1.1. Inside this file you will need to import Pipe and PipeTransform from the angular core.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
```

1.2. give your custom pipe a name

```
@Pipe({
        name: 'myListFilter'
})
```

1.3. implement the `PipeTransform` interface and use the `transform()` method to transform the value and return it

```
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: lists[], args: string[]): lists[] {
            // your javascript code goes here
        }
}
```

2. In your main `module.ts` import the custom pipe that you've created

```
import { MyFilterPipe } from './my-filter.pipe'
```

2.1. and add it to the `declarations:` array

```
declarations: [ MyFilterPipe ]
```

3. In Your `table.component.ts` class add this:

```
listFilter: string = '';
```

4. In your template add an input field and use `ngModel` for Two Way Data Binding:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="listFilter" />
```

4. anf finally apply the custom pipe to your element using the `|` operator:

```
<tr *ngFor='let list of lists | myListFilter: listFilter'>
```

You can see an example of Filtering with Input here:
http://plnkr.co/qwsk86hHLbI26w3HVMdV

Comment: thanks for quik answer! but in plunker, input filter doesnt working

Comment: You are welcome! It's working for me... Try opening it in full screen: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/qwsk86hHLbI26w3HVMdV/

Comment: error page -> run.plnkr.co/plunks/qwsk86hHLbI26w3HVMdV, when i write some symbol in input, nothing happens